# How multiplyByInverseOfAttitude (CMAttitude Class ) is implemented?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, core-motion

I need to implement the same behaviour used by multiplyByInverseOfAttitude from the CMAttitude iOS class. Please note that I cannot directly use it but I have the right CMAttitude objects. Anyone can point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are not allowed to create an instance of CMAttitude on your own, the only way is to create a new quaternion and take this for any further calculations. I recommend using your own customised quaternions class instead of the simple struct [CMQuaternion](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMAttitude_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009943-CH1-SW1). A good starting point is the [cocoamath](http://code.google.com/p/cocoamath/) project where you can take Quaternion.m, Quaternion.h and QuaternionOperations.m from [trunk](http://code.google.com/p/cocoamath/source/browse/trunk) and I will use it for this sample code.

First you have to save an instance from the [complex conjugate](http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/OpenGL%3aTutorials%3aUsing_Quaternions_to_represent_rotation#The_complex_conjugate_of_a_quaternion) of your reference quaternion (taken from `CMAttitude.quaternion`) to use for all subsequent multiplications i.e.

MyClass.h

```
Quaternion* inverseReferenceQuaternion;
```

MyClass.c

```
// initialising code run only once after each call to [motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdates];
CMAttitude firstAttitude = [motionManager deviceMotion].attitude;
CMQuaternion q = firstAttitude.quaternion;
inverseReferenceQuaternion = [[Quaternion alloc] initWithRe:q.w i:-q.x j:-q.y k:-q.z];
```

In your timer loop (or handler block) you need a [quaternion multiplication](http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/OpenGL%3aTutorials%3aUsing_Quaternions_to_represent_rotation#Multiplying_quaternions):

```
// on every update
CMAttitude attitude = [motionManager deviceMotion].attitude;
CMQuaternion current = attitude.quaternion;
Quaternion currentMultiplied = initAsProductOf:inverseReferenceQuaternion And:current
```

Now `currentMultiplied` should contain what you are looking for.

Quaternions are pretty if you are new to this subject, but it's worth to read some tutorials like for example [OpenGL:Tutorials:Using Quaternions to represent rotation](http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/OpenGL%3aTutorials%3aUsing_Quaternions_to_represent_rotation) or [Quaternion Powers](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/math-and-physics/quaternion-powers-r1095).